# win 10 + Ubuntu 18.04 -> Lubuntu 20.04

Tags: lubuntu

So I've run into trouble installing Lubuntu 20.04 on my Dell inspiron (intel Core i5 7th gen. 8mb ram 1tb HDD).

I previously dual booted with windows 10 and ubuntu 18.04 with no issues.

Decided to switch entirely to Lubuntu. Created bootable Lubuntu 20.04 usb, deleted the partition, booted from usb, installed Lubuntu without internet, clicked finish and restart, removed usb and hit enter.

When booting up my laptop still went to the GNU grub, and only gave me the option of booting from ubuntu, when i tried that got a constant black screen. I can boot from usb and lubuntu works fine, but can't without it.

Any ideas?

Comment: You must be booting old grub, but new install should have overwritten it. Or did you not install in same boot mode. Both Windows & Ubuntu/Lubuntu need to be either BIOS or both UEFI. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: In the end I  did a fresh install of mint which went fine and is up and running. May try lubuntu again later on.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to edit the BIOS EFI boot menu. Every OS installs an EFI boot loader. Through the boot menu, you can select which one to boot.

Comment: In the end I  did a fresh install of mint which went fine and is up and running. May try lubuntu again later on.